# Class with custom delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am creating a custom delegate in a class and trying to implement the protocol in my controller.
But is not working as delegate is nil.
This is how I am doing it :

**BluetoothOperations.swit**

```
protocol GetWatchCollectedData:NSObjectProtocol {
    func getWatchCollectedData(COMMAND_ID : UInt8, data : NSData)
}

class BluetoothOperations: NSObject{
    var getWatchCollectedData: GetWatchCollectedData?

    func customFunc(){
        getWatchCollectedData.getWatchCollectedData(ID,Data)
    }
}
```

**SomeController.swift**

```
class SomeController: UIViewController {
   let object = BluetoothOperations()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        object.getWatchCollectedData = self

    }
}

extension SomeController: GetWatchCollectedData{
    func getWatchCollectedData(COMMAND_ID : UInt8, data : NSData){
        print("delegate working.")
    } 
}
```

I have also tried to make an object of class and assign `BluetoothOperations's object. getWatchCollectedData = self`  in viewDidLoad but didn't work.

Any idea where I am doing it wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: BluetoothOperations's object. getWatchCollectedData = self

Comment: tried that too. but didn't work. @HarshalValanda

Comment: Is your `BluetoothOperations` Object is global object ? ,Or show how you are creating instance

Comment: let object  = BluetoothOperations(), object.getWatchCollectedData = self

Comment: @JonSnow yes it is global. updating ques.

Comment: @AshokPolu tried that too. Check updated ques pls.

Comment: @sharadchauhan can you update code and show how are you confirming to delegate in viewDidLoad()

Comment: @sharadchauhan try adding this line in videDidLoad and check-: let object = BluetoothOperation()

Comment: @sharadchauhan Please correct your question , It is quite confusing could you please put your all code combined instead of First method and second method

Comment: @JonSnow those are two diff approach right ? one with extension and one without ?

Comment: Yes  You can , Either you create extension with delegate or confirm in class itself , There is no issue I am editing your question please check after edit done

Comment: @JonSnow yes please. thanks

Comment: Could you please try to replace NSObjectProtocol with class, and also try to add init method in  BluetoothOperations

Comment: @JonSnow tried. nothing changed.

Comment: @sharadchauhan have you tried what i mentioned?

Comment: @TusharSharma yes I did. And nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct. And here is the a possible reason why it may fail. In your `SomeController`, you are creating `object` from your `BluetoothOperations` class and assigned delegate correctly.

HOWEVER, you must make sure that the object defined in your controller is sending out the delegate call. You could be having another instance of the `BluetoothOperations` and that is actually being used, AND IN THAT INSTANCE, the delegate is not set.

The easiest way to check this is to manually trigger the delegate in the object you created in your view controller. Try the following code to see if the delegate get triggered or not.

```
class SomeController: UIViewController {
   let object = BluetoothOperations()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        object.getWatchCollectedData = self
        object.customFunc()// Trigger the delegate function here
    }
}

extension SomeController: GetWatchCollectedData{
    func getWatchCollectedData(COMMAND_ID : UInt8, data : NSData){
        print("delegate working.")
    } 
}
```

Comment: okay, i did what you said, and that function is getting called from viewDidLoad.

Comment: @sharadchauhan. Okay. That means that your delegate system is working correctly. The thing goes wrong is exactly as what I said. The delegate is not set on the actuall `BluetoothOperations` object that you are running. So please make sure that the `BluetoothOperations` object initialized from your controller and the delegate is set correctlt.

Comment: @sharadchauhan Yes it is the issue , Your `customFunc` is not called from instance you are creating from  `SomeController`

Comment: @JonSnow yeah. And what shall i do to make it happen ?

Comment: @sharadchauhan Well, it depends on your code how and where and when the running `BluetoothOperations` instance exists. You can try to create a singleton object from your `BluetoothOperations` class and make sure there are not duplicated instances.

Comment: @sharadchauhan Create shared Instance of  BluetoothOperations and use it. but there is also drawbacks , Your lastly set delegate will call always

Comment: ohh. Okay i am setting instance of BluetoothOperations from another class also. So that may be the possible reason why its not getting called from my controller ? How can i make sure that it is not singleton ? thanks.

Comment: @sharadchauhan Yeah that is the cause. That means your other controller "owns" that 'GetWatchCollectedData' instance and it only reports delegate to that controller.    I am asking you to make sure you have only one instance of your `GetWatchCollectedData` class throughout the project. You can searching online for sample code. Such kind of technique is called singleton. If you don't want to do it in this way, when you switch to your `SomeController`, you must start using the new instances created in your `SomeController` because it owns the instance. Am I making sense?

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly implemented delegate but not between proper classes

As you have created object of `BluetoothOperations` in  `SomeController` and also in other View controller let's say `SomeController1`

Now The delegate is responsible for only relevant class only

like

```
`BluetoothOperations` (Call `customFunc`)     ---->  `SomeController1`
`BluetoothOperations`  (Call `customFunc`)    ---->  `SomeController`
```

And you are trying like this

```
 `SomeController1  ---> `BluetoothOperations` (Call `customFunc`)  ----> SomeController`
```

This couldn't be achieved by this way,

As your  `SomeController1` and  `SomeController` are not in connection from anywhere

It is very difficult to suggest you a answer

you create delegate between `SomeController1` and  `SomeController` both of them.

Hope it is clear to you